# AppointmentType resource

Tags: hl7-fhir

I need to return AppointmentTypes as a FHIR resource. Unfortunately, I couldn't find it as an official FHIR resource format.

My best guess would be to create a `Basic` resource, like this:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Basic",
  "id" : "id-of-appointment-type",
  "identifier" : [
    {
            "use" : "secondary",
            "system" : "http://myUrl/myIdentifier",
            "value" : "7"
   }
  ],
  "code" : {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://myUrl/appointment-type",
        "code": "appointment-type"
      }
    ]
   },
  "text" : {
        "status" : "generated",
        "div" : "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">AppointmentType</div>"
  },
  "extension": [
    {
      "url": "http://myUrl/appointment-type-name",
      "valueString": "New Patient"
    },
    {
      "url": "http://myUrl/appointment-type-availability",
      "valueBoolean": true
    }
  ],
  "meta" : {
        "lastUpdated" : "2020-05-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

Would this be the right way to create the AppointmentType resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any obvious issues, but did you evaluate using CodeSystem?  You can define properties on CodeSystem codes which would be able to distinguish available from non-available appointment types - and that would work better with Appointment, where 'type' is expected to be a code.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be a much better way of doing it. Thank you!